# Capybara drag_to method works on Windows machine but doesnot works on Linux one

Tags: google-chrome, capybara, autotest

I test ruby project through Cucumber-Capybara framework. I create a test for reoder list items by drag-n-drop method: https://rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element:drag_to

```
Given('Element {string} drag to {string}') do |elem1, elem2|
  div_groups = all(:css, "div.#{$divgroup}")
  source = div_groups[elem1.to_i-1]
  target = div_groups[elem2.to_i-1]
  source.drag_to(target)
end
```

This code works perfectly on Windows machine (win 7 + chrome) but doesn't work on Linux machine (google virtual machine).

Can anybody help?

Update:

- video record for Win machine (delay between drag operations 1.0 sec): https://disk.yandex.ru/d/F7Odxc9tuGvDPA
- video record for Linux machine https://disk.yandex.ru/d/xMEkHyKvRtbvTg (can see that drag operation doesn't happen)

2 Update:

- on linux chromedrivet 62bit, but on win PC - 32 bit

3 Update
I put forward a hypothesis and decided to check it.
I changed the code like this

```
Given('Element {string} drag to {string}') do |elem1, elem2|
  div_groups = all(:css, "div.#{$divgroup}")
  source = div_groups[elem1.to_i-1]
  target = div_groups[elem2.to_i-1]
  #source.drag_to(target, delay: 1.0)

  selenium_webdriver = page.driver.browser
  selenium_webdriver.action.click_and_hold(source.native).perform
  sleep 0.5
  selenium_webdriver.action.move_to(target.native, 0, 10).release.perform
  sleep 0.5
end
```

And it works!

Comment: What do you mean by “doesn’t work”? Do you see errors, does the drag just not appear to work, etc. Are you setting a window size to make sure the viewport is large enough to allow a drag from source to target?

Comment: Result of drag_to I check reopen the popup where I change order of rows by drag-n-drop. On win machine after reopen the popup I observe the right (new) order but on linux one I see the old (without change) order of rows.

I add wiating but it doesn't help

``` And Element "4" drag to "1"    
  And Wait 2 seconds```

Comment: There is nor any errors or I can't know how can measure them. I try to change delay value (options in drag_to method). Increase of delay (defaul 0.05 sec, I set 0.1) allow to see drag operation on screen (on win machine). But it doesnt give similar effect on linux machine. Linux machine is more powerful and faster.